# Finding duplicate records in table based on one form's textbox value and returning results into a subform

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, duplicates, subform

Please bear with me while I try my best to explain.

I have a form (frmDataEntry) that users use to data entry paper application information into a table (tblTracking). The address textbox on the form(txtAddress) is populated one of two ways - manual data entry or automatically by vba code based on the applicant's account number textbox on the form(txtAccountNumber).

I currenting have a command button that runs a Find Duplicates Parameter Query with an address criteria on the table (tblTracking). A separate window pops up with all the duplicate records.

It has become very tedious, to type in the address for a second time for every address.

I would like to have it so that, when the Me.txtaddress is entered, either manually or automatically, the filtered results from the table (tblTracking)- (ApplicationID, Firstname,LastName,Address,...) **automatically appears** in a subform datasheet.

I have tried attempting this with a subform (qryDuplicates) 
source object = tblTracking, and 
master/child fields linking form Address to subform Address, 
form (frmDataEntry) record source = tblTracking, 
but the subform only updates after you move to next record and then back.

I have also try adding the code Me.qryDuplicates.refresh in the Form, Address **or** Subform's afterupdate, beforeupdate, current, dirty, **or** change events, but it still only updates after moving to next record and then back.

Please walk me through this with explainations. I have been pulling my hair for over a week. I am literally dreaming in code.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for making this an answer it will not let me add a comment, but have you tried to use Me.qryDuplicates.requery from the main form after update with name for example. That should just work, but just in case.

It sounds like you could also do this based on a normal query with the critera related to the text boxes on the main form.

For example the criteria could be:

```
Like [Forms]![frm_RecordSearch]![txtFirst] & "*"
```

etc. where frm_RecordSearch = Your main form and txtFirst = Field name

then you could make a form based on the query and add it as a subform to your main form and use the .requery to update. If your method is already working then all you should need is the .requery, but this is another option.